# Consistent handling of division by zero in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to populate a numpy array with values from the smooth bump function

```
f(x) = exp ( - 1 / (1 - x^2) )     if |x| < 1,  f(x) =  0 otherwise
```

Currently I have something that works (as in gives me the right numbers on my platform)

```
x = linspace(-1.1 , 1.1, 300)   #Sample 300 points between [-1.1,1.1]
bump = exp( 1 - 1 / (1 - clip(square(x), 0,1)) )
```

when the absolute value of an entry in x is at least 1, its square gets clipped to 1, and we have "`1/(1-1) = 1/0 = +inf`" as "expected" on my platform, which then gets set by "`exp(1 - inf) = 0`" which is exactly the behaviour I want.

My questions:

1. I suspect that the above is not the best practice. Am I correct in my suspicions?
2. Are there better ways of handling this division by zero? At the end of the day the array `x` may not be just simply a linear list of values. So I want something that can compute `f(x)` from `x` efficiently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you want to generate DivisionByZero exceptions?

I would use masked arrays:

```
import numpy as np
x= np.linspace(-1.1,1.1,300)
masked_idx = (np.abs(x)>1)
masked_x = np.ma.array(x,mask=idx)

def f(x):
   return np.exp(-1.0/(1.0-x**2))

masked_f = f(masked_x)

plot(masked_x,masked_f)    # in IPython / pyplot
```

If you want, you can do the masking in your function (by having boundary arguments)

Comment: *shakes fist at GertVdE* for beating me to the answer.  Gert has it, use array masks, don't rely on dangerous boundaries of the floating-point standard.  For example, your code didn't work on my OS X.8 Intel Mac.

Comment: "Why do you want to generate DivisionByZero exceptions?" Because I didn't know any better. Thanks for the answer. Let me try it out.

Comment: Okay, so after I do the arithmetic on the non-zero values, I can just just use the `filled()` function to set the masked values to 0. That works great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Another take:

```
_f = lambda x: np.exp(-1.0/(1.0-x*x))
f = lambda x: np.piecewise(x, [np.abs(x) < 1, np.abs(x) >= 1], [_f, 0.0])

x = np.linspace(-1.1,1.1,300)
bump = f(x)
```

my point here is that what you really need for efficiency is a `ufunc`, possibly implemented in C. In the absence of a true `ufunc` you can go with any numpy trick.